# Inflate Button exactly at centre of the touch point on DragEvent.ACTION_DROP on AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-view, layout-inflater, absolutelayout

I want the button to be inflated with its centre point = touch point.
At the time of inflating, m doing as follows:

```
control = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button,
                    (ViewGroup) target_layout, false);
targetContainer.addView(control);

    x = x - (control.getWidth()/2);   // control not inflating exactly @ center of 
    y = y - (control.getHeight()/2); //  the touch left.
    absoluteLayoutParams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, x, y);
    control.setLayoutParams(absoluteLayoutParams);
```

**button.xml** contains button with height and width = Wrap Content.
**x** & **y** here are the touch co-ordinates at the time of releasing drag.

---

[image: This is how its getting inflated] This is how its getting inflated from the touch point.

[image: I expect it to get inflated like this] I expect it to get inflated like this from the touch point.

Thanks in advance, Kapil.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
targetContainer.addView(control);
```

after you set the layoutParams for it, something like this:

```
control = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button,
                (ViewGroup) target_layout, false);

x = x - (control.getWidth()/2);   // control not inflating exactly @ center of 
y = y - (control.getHeight()/2); //  the touch left.
absoluteLayoutParams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, x, y);
control.setLayoutParams(absoluteLayoutParams);

targetContainer.addView(control);
```

Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Tried as u suggested, still its same.